# Setup Lets Encrypt on VPS where the DNS is setup on CloudFlare

Tags: ssl, dns, vps, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I have hosted a website using VPS and pointed to it using DNS services of CloudFlare, The site is working properly. Now I am trying to install ssl provided by [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), I am able to complete the steps successfully but the site doesn't appear to be ssl enabled. Also when I completed the steps succesfully the process didn't generate any cert file.I have used the https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04 could anybody tell me were I might be going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare supports using Let's Encrypt between CloudFlare and your origin; however you must use the `--webroot` argument when you run the Let's Encrypt binary.

By using the [webroot authentication method](http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#webroot), a temporary file is placed to validate your domain for the certificate. There is a guide on how to do this on the CloudFlare help centre: [How to Validate a Let’s Encrypt Certificate on a Site Already Active on CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/214820528-How-to-Validate-a-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificate-on-a-Site-Already-Active-on-CloudFlare)

By using this method, you are able to ensure the connection between CloudFlare and your origin web server is fully encrypted using [Strict SSL](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-strict-ssl-protecting-against-a-man-in-the-middle-attack-on-origin-traffic/).

[image: CloudFlare Full SSL in Strict Mode]

Answer (score 0):

Now you have https on your server.

So the communication vpc-cloudfare can use https.

Now you have to configure cloudfare to use https betwenn cloudfare and the browsers.

See https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/